# Ec2 1/2 checks passed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Since today i can't access my instance, i tried stop and restart several times but the status is always : "1/2 checks passed"

I tried to create a snapshot, detach and reattach new volume but the result is the same.

I also tried to create another instance and attach the volume and it's not starting either.

Any help ?

Comment: There is no problem asking about sysadmin things here.

Comment: Can you please tell me where you found the stats (99.9%...) ? Why can i select "amazon-ec2" as tag on my question ? It's not written anywhere that all the question should be about programming language... If you are not able to answer my question, please don't.

Comment: In my case, there were some applications that were opened by some scripts but weren't closed because the scripts had crashed, after closing those apps manually using their process id it started showing "2/2 checks passed" again.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The status checks automatically performed on Amazon EC2 instances are:

- **System Status Checks:** These check the underlying systems used by the Amazon EC2 instance
- **Instance Status Checks:** These check the configuration of the specific instance

See documentation: [Status Checks for Your Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html)

Often, an instance is available and ready to be used before these checks are complete -- this is especially the case for Linux instances because they boot very quickly.

If you receive a `1/2 checks passed` message, either wait a little longer or Stop and Start the instance. Performing a Stop/Start will launch the instance on a different host, which will probably fix whatever problem was being experienced.

If the `1/2 checks passed` message continues to appear after a Stop/Start, it is probably a misconfiguration of the AMI. I have seen this when the wrong virtualization type was selected for an AMI that was created from a Snapshot.

You might be able to get a hint about the problem by using the **Get System Log** command in the Actions menu, which shows the log while the instance is booting.

Worst case, launch a new instance from a known-good AMI, attach the non-booting volume as an additional disk and copy files to the new disk. You will still have access to your files even if it will not boot.

Comment: Restarting the instance did the trick, TY! But can't re get alerts when such tests fail?

Comment: Start and Stop worked where "Reboot Instance" did not.

Comment: I only changed instance type and now nothing is working, cant ssh etc. Starting and stopping didnt work after I got 1/2 status check.

Answer (score 14):

You can check the description of the checks here, and understand which one is not working...

[image]