# Amazon EC2 instance passed 1/2 checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Newbie to Amazon Web Services here. I launched an instance from a Public AMI and found that I could not ssh into the instance - I received the error "Connection timed out." I checked the security groups to verify that Port 22 was associated with 0.0.0.0/0. Additionally, I checked the route tables to verify that 0.0.0.0/0 is associated with target gateway attached to the VPC.

I find that only 1/2 status checks have passed - the instance status check failed. I have tried stopping and starting the instance as well as terminated and launching a new instance, both to no avail. The error that I see in the system log is:

Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1).

From this previous question, it appears that this could be a virtualization issue, but I'm not sure if that was due to something I did on my end when launching the instance or something that occurred from the creators of the AMI? [Ec2 1/2 checks passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160224/ec2-1-2-checks-passed)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try using different AMI or different region to launch ec2 and see what happens.

Comment: I agree with @KushVyas launch an official AWS Linux AMI.  The login name is ec2-user

Answer (score 0):

Can you share any more details about how you deployed the instance? Did you use the AWS Management Console, or one of the command line tools or SDKs to deploy it? Which public AMI did you use? Was it one of the ones provided by Amazon?

Depending on your needs, I would make sure that you use one of the AMIs provided by Amazon, such as Ubuntu, Amazon Linux, CentOS, etc. Here's the links to the [docs on AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html), but you can learn quite a bit by just searching for images. Since you mentioned virtualization types though, I'd suggest reading up briefly on the HVM vs. Paravirtual virtualization types on AWS. Each of the instance types / families uses a certain virtualization type, which is indicated in the [chart on this page](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/).

### Instance Status Checks

[This documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) covers the instance status checks, which you'll probably want to familiarize yourself with. It's entirely possible that shutting down (not restart, but shutdown) and then starting the instance back up might resolve the instance status check.

### Spot Instances - cost savings!

By the way, I'll just mention this since you indicated that you're new to AWS ... if you're just playing around right now, you can save a ton of cost by deploying [EC2 Spot Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html), instead of paying the normal, on-demand rates. Depending on current rates, you can save more than 50%, and [per-second billing still applies](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/announcing-amazon-ec2-per-second-billing/). Although there's the possibility that your EC2 instance could get "interrupted" based on market demand, you can configure your Spot Instance to just "Hibernate" or "Stop" instead of terminating and relaunching. That way, your work is instance state is saved for when it relaunches.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1) Use well-known images or contact with the image developer. Perhaps it requires more than one drive or tricky partitioning.

2) make sure you selected proper HVM/PV image according to the instance type.

3) (after checks are passed) make sure the instance has public ip